# `summarise` based on `group_by` with multiple columns where one column also has `NA`

Tags: r, dplyr, na

example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), ID2 = c(11, NA, 13, NA, 14), ID3 = c(1,2,3,4,5), value = c(110, 120, 130, 140, 150))
test <- test %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2, ID3) %>%
  summarise(value=sum(value))
```

Desired output test df:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 value
1   11  1   110
2   NA  2   120
3   13  3   130
4   NA  4   140
5   14  5   150
```

But I get the following output in my data:

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 value
1   11  1   110
3   13  3   130
5   14  5   150
```

NOTE: in the example code above the result is the desired output. But in my own code, which is in essence the same but with 9 group IDs, the output excludes the rows where 1 ID column has NA values.

I dont understand why this happens, I have used groupby and summarise in a similar context where rows with NA did not get excluded.

As a cheap solution; I have solved it by first filling the NA values with a character value "NA" which are after the summarise() replaced back to real NA values. But this solution bothers me, could anybody help me out here?
example code for the solution:

```
df <- data.frame(ID1 = c(1,2,3,4,5), ID2 = c(11, NA, 13, NA, 14), ID3 = c(1,2,3,4,5), value = c(110, 120, 130, 140, 150))
test <- test %>%
  mutate(ID2 = ifelse(is.na(ID2), "NA", ID2)) %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2, ID3) %>%
  summarise(value=sum(value)) %>% 
  mutate(ID2 = ifelse(ID2 == "NA", NA, ID2))
```

Comment: It's much easier to help if you show an example that demonstrates the problem, not an example where things work as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of specific columns using mutate and sum with NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70306786/sum-of-specific-columns-using-mutate-and-sum-with-na-values)

Comment: `sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for the feedback, i have edited my question. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @MichaelRoswell No unfortunately that does not help, that question is about NA values within the column that is summed. In my case the groupby and summarise seems to exclude rows where one of the columns used in groupby() has NA values.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry I missed the intent of the question. Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51093112/8400969

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of R/ most of its functions is to ignore NA, with NA being treated as not meaningful. However, in your case, it seems that NA does contain some information and you would like to keep the NA as it is.

In this case, I would suggest for the ID columns to be coerced to character, then have the NA be stored as a character string of "NA".

```
as.character.na <- function(x){
  
  Output <- as.character(x)
  Output[is.na(Output)] <- "NA"
  return(Output)
  
}

test <- df %>%
  mutate(ID1 = as.character.na(ID1), ID2 = as.character.na(ID2),
         ID3 = as.character.na(ID3)) %>%
  group_by(ID1, ID2, ID3) %>%
  summarise(value=sum(value))
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works. What I aditionally do is return the character NA values to normal NA values after the summarise function (since this is required for the output).  I just wished that there was another solution within groupby() or summarise().